# Trouble showing FIles. asp.net core

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

Hello i am having trouble showing an Image and a PDF on my View.
When i click on the the button that opens the modal to show the image it says that it can't be showed because it contains errors. The PDF file shows empty, and when i donwload it its 0 bytes.

Here is the Model:

```
public class Libro
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Titulo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, ingrese el titulo del libro.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Autor")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, ingrese el nombre del autor.")]
    public string Autor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name ="Foto de Portada")]
    public string Portada { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Editorial")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, ingrese el nombre de la editorial")]
    public string Editorial { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Año de Publicacion")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Por favor, ingrese el año en que se publico el libro.")]
    public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Libro PDF")]
    public string ArchivoPdf { get; set; }
}
```

My View code (its the same for the PDF file, except for the `<img>` tag):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPortada">
      Ver Imagen
</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPortada" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Portada</h3>
                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
             <div style="text-align: center;">
                 <img src="@Url.Content(item.Portada)"/>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My controller Index action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await _context.Libros.ToListAsync());
        }
```

And how i upload the files to my wwwroot folder:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(LibrosViewModel libro)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(libro);
            }

            Libro libroNuevo = await DameLibroConArchivos(libro);

            _context.Add(libroNuevo);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
```

```
private async Task<Libro> DameLibroConArchivos(LibrosViewModel libro)
        {
            Libro libroNuevo = new Libro();
            libroNuevo.Id = libro.Id;
            libroNuevo.Title = libro.Title;
            libroNuevo.Autor = libro.Autor;
            libroNuevo.Editorial = libro.Editorial;
            libroNuevo.PublishDate = libro.PublishDate;
            if (libro.filePortada != null)
            {
                string pathPortada = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ArchivosLibros/Portadas/" + libro.Title.Replace(" ", "_"));
                libroNuevo.Portada = Path.Combine(pathPortada, libro.filePortada.FileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(pathPortada))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathPortada);
                }
                using (var stream1 = new FileStream(Path.Combine(pathPortada,libro.filePortada.FileName) , FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await libro.filePortada.CopyToAsync(stream1);
                }
            }
            if (libro.filePdf != null)
            {
                string pathPdf = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "ArchivosLibros/Libros/" + libro.Title.Replace(" ", "_"));
                libroNuevo.ArchivoPdf = Path.Combine(pathPdf, libro.filePdf.FileName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(pathPdf))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(pathPdf);
                }
                using (var stream2 = new FileStream(Path.Combine(pathPdf,libro.filePdf.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await libro.filePdf.CopyToAsync(stream2);
                }
            }
            return libroNuevo;
        }
``
```

Comment: You could always press F12 in your browser to check the console to see the error, it is like that the Url,Content is not set correctly.

Comment: I did not know that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your url is correct at first.

Since your `item.Portada` stores the absolute path of your image which is similar to

`C:\\your project path\\wwwroot\\ArchivosLibros\\Libros\\title_name\\filename.png`

The `<img src="@Url.Content(item.Portada)"/>` could not render it correctly and resulted in 404 error.

It only needs the relative path after the `wwroot`:

`<img src="@Url.Content("\\ArchivosLibros\\Libros\\title_name\\filename.png")" />`

So, trying to modify it to below could resolve it.

```
<img src="@Url.Content(item.Portada.Substring(item.Portada.IndexOf("wwwroot")).Substring(7))" />
```

Comment: @ferbau Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  if you have resolved the problem?